# Transfer hashmaps across fragments Android

Tags: java, android

**Say I have:**

```
private Map<Integer,String> prices = new HashMap<Integer,String>();
private Map<Integer,String> titles = new HashMap<Integer,String>();
private Map<Integer,String> descriptions = new HashMap<Integer,String>();
private Map<Integer,String[]> pictures = new HashMap<Integer,String[]>();
```

**I want to transfer these to another fragment via bundle:**

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.put  //best way?
fragment.setArguments(bundle);
if (fragment != null) {
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
    .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();
}
```

What would be the most efficient/simplest way to do this?

Comment: You don't necessarily need to 'put' it in a bundle. You can create a 'setter' as @Ammar suggested and it should be ideally called anytime before `beginTransaction()` gets called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a setter of these `HashMap`s in your fragment class. then use it to pass these parameters to fragment.

```
fragment.setHashMaps(Map<Integer,String> prices, Map<Integer,String> titles, Map<Integer,String> descriptions, Map<Integer,String[]> pictures) {
    this.prices = prices;
    this.titles= titles;
    this.descriptions = descriptions;
    this.pictures = pictures;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, sometimes you over-think things :)